# The buttons on my hero section are not displaying (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, reactjs, jsx

I'm writing a web application and need a simple UI. I was following a bunch of different tutorials and taking what I needed. I worked on the navbar successufully and have it displaying and buttons working. However, the hero section for my home page simply doesnt display. I tried changing the css file and tried all the troubleshooting steps i could find but they didnt work. Here is my code:

HeroSection.css:

```
.hero-container {
  
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  object-fit: contain;
}

.hero-container > h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 100px;
  margin-top: -100px;
}

.hero-container > p {
  margin-top: 8px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande',
    'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}

.hero-btns {
  margin-top: 32px;
}

.hero-btns .btn {
  margin: 6px;
}

.fa-play-circle {
  margin-left: 4px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  .hero-container > h1 {
    font-size: 70px;
    margin-top: -150px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .hero-container > h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
    margin-top: -100px;
  }

  .hero-container > p {
    font-size: 30px;
  }

  .btn-mobile {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  .btn {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

HeroSection.js

```
import React from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import { Button } from './Button';
import './HeroSection.css';

function HeroSection() {
  return (
    <div className='hero-container'>
      
      <h1>HI</h1>
      <p>What are you waiting for?</p>
      <div className='hero-btns'>
        <Button
          className='btns'
          buttonStyle='btn--outline'
          buttonSize='btn--large'
        >
          GET STARTED
        </Button>
        <Button
          className='btns'
          buttonStyle='btn--primary'
          buttonSize='btn--large'
          onClick={console.log('hey')}
        >
          CLICK <i className='far fa-play-circle' />
        </Button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default HeroSection;
```

Button.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import './Button.css';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const STYLES = ['btn--primary', 'btn--outline'];

const SIZES = ['btn--medium', 'btn--large'];

export const Button = ({
  children,
  type,
  onClick,
  buttonStyle,
  buttonSize
}) => {
  const checkButtonStyle = STYLES.includes(buttonStyle)
    ? buttonStyle
    : STYLES[0];

  const checkButtonSize = SIZES.includes(buttonSize) ? buttonSize : SIZES[0];

  return (
    <Link to='/sign-up' className='btn-mobile'>
      <button
        className={`btn ${checkButtonStyle} ${checkButtonSize}`}
        onClick={onClick}
        type={type}
      >
        {children}
      </button>
    </Link>
  );
};
```

Button.css:

```
:root {
    --primary: #fff;
}

.btn{
    padding: 8px 20px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.btn--primary{
    background-color: var(--primary);
    color: #242424;
    border: 1px solid var(--primary)

}

.btn--outline{
    background-color: transparent;
    color : #fff;
    padding: 8px 20px;
    border: 1px solid var(--primary);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;

}

.btn--medium{
    padding: 8px 20px;
    font-size: 20px;

}
.btn--large{
    padding: 12px 26px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.btn--medium:hover, 
.btn--large:hover{
    background: #fff;
    color: #242424;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you added `HeroSection` to your `App.jsx`?

Your styles look fine and i dont see anything wrong with your component. You can set default value for your props instead of check and assign value to styles in `Button` component.